# How to prove smoothness and convexity of the composite Logsumexp function.

Tags: convex-analysis, smooth-functions

Given a function $g(\boldsymbol{x})$,

$g(\boldsymbol{x})=log(\sum_{i=1}^{m}e^{\frac{f_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})}{\lambda_{i}}})$,
where $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $f_{i}$ is a $L_{i}$-smooth function. $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{m}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}=1$.

How to prove the smoothness and covexity of $g(\boldsymbol{x})$?

I have an idea, but I'm not sure can I do better.
\begin{aligned}
&||\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g(\mathbf{x_1}|\lambda)-\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g(\mathbf{x_2}|\lambda)|| \\
&=||\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \\
&\leq\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \\&
=\sum_{i=1}^m ||\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} \nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} \nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})+\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} \nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})-\frac{\lambda_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}} \nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \\ &
\sum_{i=1}^m ||\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} (\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}}))+(\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}})\cdot \nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \\&
\leq \sum_{i=1}^m ||\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} (\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}}))+(\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}})\cdot ||\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \ || \\&
\sum_{i=1}^m ||\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}} || \ ||\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})-\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})||+||\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{1}})}{\lambda_{i}}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}\frac{e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}{\sum_{i}e^\frac{f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})}{\lambda_{i}}}||\cdot ||\nabla f_{i}(\mathbf{x_{2}})|| \ ||
\end{aligned}

The first term is smooth because $f_{i}$ is $L_{i}$-smooth, I don't know how to proceed after that, or is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.